# how to dedug in eclipse and solve Unknown Source erros

Tags: java, eclipse

```
/*this is my java code which when i compile they don not show exactly error */

public class Login {

    public JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    Connection conections;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public Login() {
        initialize();
        conections = SqliteConnectio.dbConnection();

    }



    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 581, 411);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(266, 112, 193, 45);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnLOGIN = new JButton("LOGIN");
        Image jn=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Ok.png")).getImage();
        btnLOGIN.setIcon(new ImageIcon(jn));
        btnLOGIN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query = "select *from customer.sqlite where username=? and password=? ";
                    PreparedStatement pre = conections.prepareStatement(query);
                    pre.setString(1, textField.getText());
                    pre.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
                    ResultSet res = pre.executeQuery();

                    int count = 0;
                    while (res.next()) {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "username and password has sucseeful inserted");

                    } else if (count > 1) {JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "username and password has sucseeful inserted");
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "username and password has been failed to be entered");
                    }
                    res.close();
                    pre.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "you have failed to asses the database");
                }
            }
        });
        btnLOGIN.setBounds(321, 256, 125, 36);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLOGIN);

        JLabel userNAME = new JLabel("USERNAME");
        userNAME.setBounds(156, 127, 85, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(userNAME);

        JLabel passLABEL = new JLabel("PASSWORD");
        passLABEL.setBounds(156, 191, 85, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passLABEL);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(266, 188, 193, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        Image im=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/login.png")).getImage();
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(im));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 21, 136, 205);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    }
}
```

//this is my connection to  database which it seems to work just fine by prompting "username and password has sucseeful inserted"

```
package mi;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class SqliteConnectio {
    Connection conect=null;
    public static Connection dbConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
            Connection conect=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:sqlite:E:\\JAVA WORLD\\sgliteDatabase\\customer.sqlite");  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sucessful login to database");
            return conect;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "failed to login in database");
            return null;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your comments only indicate that both pieces of code are fine. What is the error then?

Comment: my problem is when i run it doesn't work it gives me this error

Comment: String query = "select *from customer.sqlite where username=? and password=? ";
                    PreparedStatement pre = conections.prepareStatement(query);
                    pre.setString(1, textField.getText());
                    pre.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
                    ResultSet res = pre.executeQuery();

Comment: If a file named “*customer.sqlite*” does indeed exist in your “*E:\JAVA WORLD\sgliteDatabase*” folder (is it really “s**g**lite” rather than “s**q**lite”?), I would check if it helps to rename the folder (and also fix the path in code) so that there are no whitespaces in the path at all. Then I would call some `Connection` methods, such as `isValid()` or `getSchema()`, to check whether your `connections` variable does indeed reference a valid database connection.